# Stop words inconsistent with preprocessing in sklearn CountVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-mining, countvectorizer

I have been trying to use the Count Vectorizer from sklearn library, however i receive the warning that the list of spanish stop words i am using are not consistent with preprocessing.

Is it an encoding problem??

The stopwords.txt file has one word per row like:

a
el
los
...

```
custom_stop_words = []
with open( "stopwords.txt", "r" ,encoding='latin_1') as fin:
    for line in fin.readlines():
        custom_stop_words.append( line.strip() )
# note that we need to make it hashable
print("Stopword list has %d entries" % len(custom_stop_words) )


from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
# use a custom stopwords list, set the minimum term-document frequency to 20
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words = custom_stop_words, min_df = 2,strip_accents='unicode',encoding="latin-1")
A = vectorizer.fit_transform(df_final['visita'])
print( "Created %d X %d document-term matrix" % (A.shape[0], A.shape[1]) )
```